# How to bind QML /C++ class on QtQuick2ControlsApplicationViewer

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

Currently I'm developing QtQuick application by QtCreator3.0.0, Qt5.2.0, and MSVC2012.
I want to make an application that calls C++ function from qml. 
Based on [this article](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22685).
it works when I use QtQuick2ApplicationViewer for QtQuick2 application.

[main.cpp]

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "testclass.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    TestClass cppObj;
    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("cppObj", &cppObj);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/QtQuick2CppTest/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

For QtQuick Controls application, it requires QtQuick2ControlsApplicationViewer instead of QtQuick2ApplicationViewer. But it doesn't have the method "rootContext()".

**How should I bind QML and C++ class in this case.**

Answer (score 1):

I got [the workaround](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/37597/) from Qt project forum.